# Retrieving file from mysql database table using java

Tags: java, mysql

I have developed a LAN client server chat application in java.In this application user can create conference group as well.A user can transfer files of any type in a conference.Now if any user sends a file to all users of the conference and suppose a user who is also a member of the conference is offline in that case the file is stored in a mysql database and later when that user logs in it will be sent to him by retrieving file from mysql database.

1)Now my question is that file can be of any type say .png,.jpg,.txt,.doc etc.Now i want to know how to retrieve these files from mysql database as well as store them wherever the user wants to without changing contents of the file.

2)Can anyone please tell me which Input and Output stream to use so that while retrieving and storing file its contents are not changed.Please note all these files are stored in the same column(ex file_contents),datatype used is longblob.

Comment: Please format your question, so we could understand.

Comment: Have you tried to use java.sql.Blob ?

Comment: @auntyellow-no i have not yet tried it will try and get back to you